# Overlaying a transparent div, which when clicked disappears

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am looking to have a transparent div on an HTML page with a graphic on which it has instructions for the user on how to use the page. When anywhere on the page is clicked or pressed then the div will hide/disappear.

I have JavaScript code which I have taken from another post on Stack Overflow, but I cannot seem to get it working.

It is linked to my HTML page and CSS, and the div is appearing, but it isn't disappearing when clicked.

How can I do this?

HTML code is as below:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="home_text">
        <!-- Your image -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

#home_text {
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    var overlay = ('#overlay');
    overlay.on('click', function (e) {
        overlay
            .hide()
            .off();
    });
});
```

Comment: You are using jQuery not pure javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `$` sign:

```
var overlay = $('#overlay');
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CTBQa/)

If you check your JavaScript console, you will see an error pointing to this line of code.

Answer (score 5):

You have missed the "$" character before `("#overlay")`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var overlay = $('#overlay');
    overlay.on('click', function (e) {
        overlay
            .hide()
            .off();
    });
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ks38e/6/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I have gone through and amended so it matches the above code, but still doesn't work. Anything else it may be?

Comment: have you gone through the fiddle I provided? you want something like this or something different? @user3437161

Comment: Yes the fiddle you provided is great, that's exactly how I need it to work and I copied the code exactly from the fiddle into my HTML,CSS and Javascript but the div still won't disappear when clicked.

Comment: I guess some problem with your jquery..which version you are using? @user3437161

Comment: I also have another part to my javascript, would that be affecting it at all? 

function readmore(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    var spoiler = document.getElementById('spoiler');
    
    if(spoiler.style.display=='none') {
        spoiler.style.display = '';
        btn.innerHTML = "Read Less ...";
    } else {
        spoiler.style.display = 'none';
        btn.innerHTML = "Read More ...";
    }   
}

Comment: @user3437161 why you have removed the accepted answer :(

Answer (score -1):

The HTML has a minor error, the  of the "overlay" should be closed:

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="home_text">
    <!-- Your image -->
</div>
```

That works on the fiddle above